# select all rows but modifying a date format

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a table called `data` where I have multiple columns of multiple times, and the table columns are dynamic.

I need to display it in a table, so I do `select * from data` but when the date columns are displaying like this `2018-10-10T18:30:00.000Z` but the type of the column is `date`.

Should I modify it and then display or it is because of something else?

Comment: If you don't like the format, then go ahead and use something like `DATE_FORMAT` to get the format you want.

Comment: If you want just date only, then you can use `Date()` function.

Comment: I wouldn't change the type, it's well as is. As suggested Tim and Madhur, you can format it in the query. You can keep the query as is and format it in the application. I don't see what's wrong with that format

Comment: I do `select * from data`, is there any way for changing it in the query?

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data.someDate, ...` Take a look at [DATE_FORMAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) documentation